# Delaying between animations in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, xcode4.5

I'm trying to delay between turning each button's alpha to 0.0, but what I have is not working.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:.25 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{button.alpha = 0.0;
            button2.alpha = 0.0;
            button3.alpha = 0.0;
            button4.alpha = 0.0;
            button5.alpha = 0.0;} completion:^(BOOL finished){ ; }];
```

How does one animate with a delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delay is to start the animation, not a delay between each change in the animation block.

You've made things unnecessarily difficult on yourself by having a sequence of buttons and deciding to create individual variables manually instead of using an array.  If you've got a collection of variables, you should usually store them in a collection of some sort.

Here's one way you could do it if they were in an array:

```
NSUInteger i = 0;
float duration = 1.5f;
for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.25f+duration*i UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
        button.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:NULL];
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: I tried using an array but I couldn't get it to work for other things that my app is doing, otherwise I would have used an array of buttons.  I will try to get an array of buttons to work again and try an implementation like this.

Comment: @user1595883 You can create an array of buttons inplace, e.g. `NSArray* buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2..., nil]`